# What is the major product of the reaction of 2-methylbuta-1,3-diene with HBr?

Tags: organic-chemistry, c-c-addition

What is the product of the reaction of 2-methylbuta-1,3-diene (isoprene) with HBr?

[image: 2-methylbuta-1,3-diene]

What I understand is that carbon (2) will get a positive charge after protonation.

But after this, which should be the major product?

- 3-bromo-3-methylbut-1-ene – because in this case the carbocation would be stable because of being tertiary, but the double bond would have less number of hyperconjugated structures and will be less stable

[image: 3-bromo-3-methylbut-1-ene]

- 1-bromo-3-methylbut-2-ene –  as the carbocation would be less stable because it would be primary but the double bond would be much more stable because of 8 $\alpha$ hydrogen available

[image: 1-bromo-3-methylbut-2-ene]